# In NumPy, is np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) different from np.array([[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]])?

Tags: arrays, matlab, numpy

I switched from Matlab/Octave to SciPy/NumPy recently, and I like it. But I found sometimes I get confused due to subtle differences.

In Matlab, when we declare a "row vector" of size 5, then we use the following command:

```
x = [1, 2, 3 ,4, 5]  % in matlab
```

The size of this vector may be checked using the "`size`" command as shown below:

```
size(x)

ans =

     1     5
```

I had assumed that the following in NumPy is doing the same thing as above.

```
 x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])  # in NumPy
```

But the size is somewhat weird.

```
>>> np.shape(x)
(5,)
```

The size is not `(5, 1)`, but it is `(5, )`. What does it exactly mean? I'm not quite sure why the second element of this tuple is empty.

I checked that the following returns (5, 1)

```
y = np.array([[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]) 
np.shape(y)
(5, 1)
```

Then, is "y" the same as "x" in NumPy? I assume it is not. I might be misunderstanding something, but could any one enlighten me on this topic?

Thanks!

Comment: In MATLAB a matrix has atleast 2 dimensions (years ago it had exactly 2).  In numpy an array can have any number - 0, 1, 2 etc.  Another signficant difference - MATLAB 'pads' array dimensions at the end, hence the `(5,1)` shape.  numpy adds them at the start - if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! But I think it is not true that MATLAB "pads" array dimension at the end. As you mentioned, in Matlab, a matrix has 2-dimension, and a vector is assumed to be a special type of matrices with a dimension of N x 1 or 1 X N. So the size of a row vector becomes [1, N].  If it is a column vector, then the size becomes [N, 1].

Comment: If I ask for `10th` dimension, it has no problem tellling me `1`: `size(1:10,10)`.

Answer (score 7):

The shape of a NumPy array is always a tuple.  `(5)` is not a tuple since Python evaluates it to be equal to the number 5. To obtain a tuple, one must add a comma after the 5, as in `(5,)`.
Thus, `(5,)` is a tuple containing 1 value, the number 5 and 
`(5, 1)` is a tuple containing 2 values, the numbers 5 and 1.

The number of elements in the tuple equals the number dimensions of the array. In NumPy lingo, dimensions are also called "axes". 
So

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

is an array of shape `(5,)`, and it has 1 dimension.

In contrast,

```
y = np.array([[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]])
```

is an array of shape `(5, 1)` and has 2 dimensions.
Thus, `x` and `y` are not the same.

---

Note in NumPy lingo, the "size" or an array refers to the number of values in the array:

```
In [48]: x.size
Out[48]: 5

In [49]: y.size
Out[49]: 5
```

---

NumPy arrays can ["broadcast"](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) their values to act like arrays of higher dimension. Since broadcasting can add new axes *to the left side* of an array's shape, an array of shape `(5,)` can broadcast to shape `(1, 5)`.

Since for 2-dimensional arrays the first axis can be thought of as corresponding to the rows and the second axis the columns, a 1-dimensional array like `x` can behave like a 1-row, 5-column array -- i.e. a row vector.
`y` has shape `(5, 1)` which makes it a 5-row, 1-column array -- i.e. a column vector.

If you add an array of shape `(1, 5)` (i.e. a row vector) with an array of shape `(5, 1)` (i.e. a column vector), the broadcasting rules produces an array of shape `(5, 5)`:

```
In [60]: x + y
Out[60]: 
array([[ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])
```

If you want `x` to act like a column vector, you would need to add a new axis *on the right*. Broadcasting never does that, so you have to do it manually with `x[:, np.newaxis]`.
Adding two column vectors produces another column vector:

```
In [61]: x[:, np.newaxis].shape
Out[61]: (5, 1)

In [56]: x[:, np.newaxis] + y
Out[56]: 
array([[ 2],
       [ 4],
       [ 6],
       [ 8],
       [10]])
```